# Django Leaflet Back-end Service for Map Screenshot

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, mapbox, django

I am developing an application in Django using leaflet, i have a questionnaire that when user fill they type the address, and then using google address api, i fetch the address details e.g. lat/long.

I want to save screenshot of 10 kilometer radius of that location in the database. How can i get the screenshot with the tile layer added using a rest service with Django dynamically without opening the map, and take save canvas from there ?